# How to find the deprotonation percentage of an acid?

Tags: acid-base, ph, concentration

> Given is an aqueous solution of mandelic acid (M = 152.2 g/mol; $pK_a$ = 3.4) with a molar concentration of 0.3 mol/ liter. A $\mathrm{pH}$ value of $2$ is measured for the aqueous mandelic acid solution. What percentage of the dissolved mandelic acid is deprotonated?

---

I know deprotonation means the removal of a $\ce{H+}$ from the acid. After googling , I found the deprotonation percentage can be obtained by dividing the $\ce{H+}$ concentration by the initial acid concentration. Deprotonation percentage shows what percent of $\ce{H+}$ is removed from the initial acid

However, I am unsure about how to proceed because it seems to me there are different ways that give a similar results, is this normal ? For example, we could just do

$$\mathrm{pH}=-\log_{10}([\ce{H+}])\rightarrow10^{-\mathrm{pH}}=10^{-2}=[\ce{H+}] \rightarrow[\ce{H+}]/0.3= 0.0333 = 3.33 \% $$

or we could do

$$K_\mathrm a=10^{-\mathrm pK_\mathrm a}=10^{-3.4}$$

$$K_\mathrm a=[\ce{H+}][\ce{A-}]/[\ce{HA}]\rightarrow K_\mathrm a=x^2/0.3\rightarrow\sqrt{0.3\times10^{-3.4}}=x=[\ce{H+}]$$

$$[\ce{H+}]/0.3 = 0.0364 = 3.64 \%$$

Are both ways correct ? Or is there another way to proceed ? I googled quite a bit but was unable to find a clear explanation

Comment: @wengen . The following information is absurd :$\ce{10^{−2}=[H+] → [H+]/0.3=3.33 }$

Comment: Is there any difference between "deprotonation percentage" and "dissociation degree $\ce{\alpha}$" ?

Comment: @Maurice IMHO,  the difference is just the proportionality constant 100 and the wording. I am not sure if I have ever seen the former until now. // Generally, if one searches A by searching its rarely used/unused synonym B, one may not find A.

Comment: pH is an extra info there. You can get the result directly from the provided pH, or you can calculate pH from the other data. Note that both values may differ.

Comment: @Poutnik By functions with dissociation degree, do you mean adding a coefficient in front of the concentration ? What would be the point of doing that ?

Comment: @Poutnik So it's normal both values differ ? I found this post where they say to do what I did, do you agree with them ? https://lavelle.chem.ucla.edu/forum/viewtopic.php?t=72640

Comment: @Maurice You are from Lausanne ? So weird to meet a fellow Swiss here, I'm from Pully (east of Lausanne)

Comment: $$K_\mathrm a=\frac{[\ce{H+}][\ce{A-}]}{[\ce{HA}]} = \frac{(c \alpha)(c \alpha)}{c(1-\alpha)} =  c \frac{\alpha^2 }{ 1-\alpha} $$

Comment: @Poutnik So this is simply algebra ? We simply use a coefficient to represent this "dissociation" ? That makes a lot of sense seen like that, in this case this is a quadratic formula we need to solve. If the percentage is really small like in our case, can we simply ignore the "$- \alpha$" in the denominator like we do with the $- x$ when finding the concentration $K_a = x^2 / (c - x)$ ?

Comment: @ wengen. Happy to meet a neighbor. Is there a private part of SE where we could have private discussions ?

Comment: @Maurice I don't think there is, but feel free to send me a chat request/ message on my Reddit account https://www.reddit.com/user/Lost_Woodpecker5064 , we could chat there

Comment: @Maurice If you have Quora or Discord, we could also chat there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Poutnik stated, one of the values you provided is extra. Let's try to make everything tidier.

Complex protonated entities aside, what chemical species are we really dealing with? $\ce{[HA], [A^-], [H_3O+]}$. The concentration of $\ce{H2O}$ shall remain constant. Right off the bat, we are dealing with 3 unknowns: the concentrations of the aforementioned species. *Wait!* - you protest - *I know $\ce{[H3O+]}$, it's given in the problem as the $\mathrm{pH}$ value!* Let's try to ignore that for the time being. Let's pretend we were given only the initial concentration (I shall denote it as $\ce{C^0_{HA}}$ where $\ce{HA}$ and $\ce{A-}$ are, of course, the acid and its conjugate base) and the $\mathrm{pK_a}$. Would one still be able to calculate this *mystifying deprotonation percentage* without being force-fed a $\mathrm{pH}$ value?

At any point, we could define the deprotonation percentage intuitively as:
$$p = 100\cdot \frac{\ce{[A-]}}{\ce{[HA]}+\ce{[A-]}} = \frac{\ce{[A-]}}{\ce{C^0_{HA}}}$$
This is not a formula worth memorizing, it could be readily derived intuitively. A *deprotonation percentage* entails determining... well, what *percentage* of your initial acid exists as the *deprotonated form* ($\ce{[A-]}$). When it comes to any problem of equilibrium, especially in the realm of simple proton-transfer equilibria, one should write down balances: mass balances, charge balances and the expression of the acidity constant(s).
$$
\ce{C^0_{HA} = [HA] + [A-]}
\tag{1 - mass balance}
$$
$$
\ce{[H3O+] = [HA-]}
\tag{2 - charge balance}
$$
$$
\mathrm{K_a} = \frac{\ce{[A-]\cdot [H3O+]}}{\ce{[HA]}}
\tag{3 - the acidity constant}
$$

3 unknowns, 3 equations! This should be more than possible to solve! But then, why are we given the $\mathrm{pH}$ supplementarily? If our system of equations is totally solvable, we should be able to calculate the $\mathrm{pH}$ on our own and, should it be different from the one in the problem statement, come up with an explanation, right?

Simple algebraic manipulation from the 3 equations **alone** leads to:
$$
\ce{ C^0_{HA} = [HA] + [A-] = [A-] \left(1 + \frac{[H3O+]}{\mathrm{K_a}} \right)  \Rightarrow [A-] = \frac{C^0_{HA}}{1+\frac{[H3O+]}{\mathrm{K_a}} } }
$$

$$
\ce{ [H3O+] = [A-] \Rightarrow [H3O+] = \frac{ C^0_{HA} }{ 1+\frac{ [H3O+] }{ \mathrm{K_a} } }  \Rightarrow C^0_{HA} = \frac{ [H3O+]^2 }{ \mathrm{K_a} } + [H3O+]} \Leftrightarrow
$$
$$\ce{ \Leftrightarrow [H3O+]^2 + [H3O+]\cdot \mathrm{K_a} - C^0_{HA}\mathrm{K_a} = 0}
$$
Upon solving this 2nd-degree polynomial, we arrive at a $\mathrm{pH}$ of $\sim \textbf{1.97}$. Not that far away from 2! But not exactly 2 either.
By plugging in this value in the identities above we arrive at:

$$
\ce{ [H3O+] = [A-] = 1.073 \cdot 10^{-2} \mathrm{M} \Rightarrow p \approx \textbf{3.58}\% \\ [HA] = 2.893 \cdot 10^{-1} \mathrm{M} }
$$

But this $\mathrm{pH}$ is still not **2**. We could, for sure, accept the kindness of the authors of the problem of providing us with an approximation for the $\mathrm{pH}$, and then rejoice in our victory. Or, we could accept the $\mathrm{pH}$ value from the problem statement as a buffered one. On many occasions, analytical chemistry makes use of [buffer solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_solution): mixtures of weak acid/conjugate base couples meant to keep the $\mathrm{pH}$ steady. In this sense, there is absolutely nothing stopping us from attaining a $\mathrm{pH}$ of absolute 2, with the assumptions made above still in place.

However, expect something to change! Well, the acidity constant won't change: it's constant! The mass balance won't change: after all, all of your mandelic/mandelate species come from the initial small quantity of mandelic acid we put in - $\ce{C^0_{HA}}$ - there's no mandelate or acid popping up from the ether. It's the **charge balance** that changes, as adding a buffer will add a new charged species into the equation (in this case, we want to make the $\mathrm{pH}$ more basic, from 1.97 to 2, we could add small quantities of $\ce{NH3/NH4Cl}$ which will add $\ce{NH4+}$ into the balance).

If you want your answer to be precise, as long as your $\mathrm{pH}$ is different from the 1.97 value we calculated earlier, you can no longer assume that pristine charge balance: your balance will be spoilt by the addition of whatever changes it from 1.97 to 2. Since a buffer is meant to keep the $\mathrm{pH}$ steady, we could determine $\ce{[A-]}$ by using the exact same equation as above:

$$
\ce{ [A-] = \frac{C^0_{HA}}{ 1+\frac{ [H3O+] }{ \mathrm{K_a} } } } = \frac{0.3}{ 1+\frac{ 10^{-2} }{ 10^{-3.4 } } } = 1.149 \cdot 10^{-2}\  \mathrm{M}
$$

Finally, $$ p = 100 \cdot \ce{ \frac{ [A-] }{ C^0_{HA} }} = 3.83\% $$

Comment: Wouah, it makes much more sense after reading this. Thanks a lot for the thorough explanation !